# Ansible remote copy loop with scp -3

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook that copies a directory from remote_host1 to remote_host2, using `scp -3p` command, where remote_host1 name is created by interpolating some fixed string with a variable value, and remote_host2 is an iterator that picks values from the inventory hosts or from one of the groups, but which host/group in particular is in turn the value of another variable. Let's show snippets from my code.

I have the following directory structure:

```
/playbook.yml
/copy_webapp/tasks/main.yml
/copy_webapp/defaults/main.yml
/inventory/hosts.yml
```

Here are the inventory contents:

```
client1:
  hosts:
    websrv1:
      ansible_host: websrv1.client1.cloud
      ansible_port: 21212
      ansible_user: webapp
    websrv2:
      ansible_host: websrv2.client1.cloud
      ansible_port: 21212
      ansible_user: webapp
```

My playbook contains:

```
- name: copy webapp
  hosts: client1

  roles:
  - copy_webapp
```

The `copy_webapp/defaults/main.yml` file contains:

```
webapp_basedir: /srv/webapp
template: -dev
```

And, finally, here is how I tried to put all that toghether in the `copy_webapp/tasks/main.yml` file:

```
- name: Copy webapp
  ansible.builtin.command: scp -3p webapp{{ template }}.mydomain.com:{{ webapp_basedir }} {{ desthost }}:{{ webapp_basedir }}
```

which needs the `desthost` variable to be defined upon Ansible invocation. Problem is, when I run:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/ playbook.yml --extra-vars "desthost=websrv1"
```

`{{ desthost }}` does get interpolated to "websrv1", but it does not get looked up in the inventory, and Ansible tells `ssh` to connect literally to "websrv1" on port 22, failing.

I understand I'm asking Ansible a bit too much here, but I couldn't find the correct way to do what I'm trying to do. I can also avoid variables and use a different playbook for each remote host or group, but then I don't know how to loop over the group items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean...you wouldn't expect `desthost` to get looked up in the inventory. It just a variable; Ansible has no way to know that it's a hostname (and `scp` doesn't know anything about Ansible inventories).

If you want to look up that variable in your inventory, you're going to need to do that explicitly:

```
- name: Copy webapp
  command: >
    scp -3p
    webapp{{ template }}.mydomain.com:{{ webapp_basedir }}
    {{ hostvars[desthost].ansible_host }}:{{ webapp_basedir }}
```

If you expect to use a custom port for `scp`, then according to the `scp` man page you need to use the URI form of the host/path argument:

```
- hosts: client1
  tasks:
  - name: Copy webapp
    delegate_to: localhost
    command: >
      scp -3p
      webapp{{ template }}.mydomain.com:{{ webapp_basedir }}
      scp://{{ hostvars[desthost].ansible_host }}:{{ hostvars[desthost].ansible_port }}/{{ webapp_basedir }}
```

Comment: Now I feel deeply stupid... thank you very much :D . Can you please expland on your answer and add how to loop over a group of hosts?

Comment: "Looping over a group of hosts" is fundamentally what Ansible does. Just create play that targets the desired host group and tasks in that play will be run for each host. If you want the task to run on your local machine (which I think is your goal?), use `delegate_to` as in the updated example.

Comment: Yes, but I need the group name to be specified through a variable, not hardcoded in the playbook. So if I set `hosts: "{{ desthost }}"` in the playbook, then how do I lookup the hostname in the role task?

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Is `desthost` a single host, or is it the name of a host group?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm so noob I don't even remember what I was after two hours ago... now it works, thanks!